# Doing an atomic read in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, atomic, memory-barriers

I have a thread-safe class, a cancel token, that transitions from an unstable mutable state (not cancelled) to a stable immutable state (cancelled). Once an instance has become immutable, I'd like to stop paying the cost of acquiring a lock before checking the state.

Here's a simplification of what things look like now:

```
-(bool) isCancelled {
    @synchronized(self) {
        return _isCancelled;
    }
}
-(bool) tryCancel {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (_isCancelled) return false;
        _isCancelled = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and what I want to try:

```
-(bool) isCancelled {
    bool result;
    // is the following correct?
    // can the two full barriers be reduced to a single read-acquire barrier somehow?
    OSMemoryBarrier();
    result = _isCancelled != 0;
    OSMemoryBarrier();
    return result;
}
-(bool) tryCancel {
    return OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32Barrier(0, 1, &_isCancelled);
}
```

Is using two memory barriers the correct approach? How should I expect it to compare to the cost of acquiring a lock (insert standard refrain about profiling here)? Is there a cheaper way to do it?

Comment: I have deleted my answer, because you don't understand it. Toward of what are in documentation you should know there are other functions, which are called by Apple's code. In plus from version to version Apple like to change his code and declare some functions deprecated and in next version completely remove it. This is the reality, which is not in documentations, but in Real Life

Comment: @matheszabi Apple is not going to deprecate atomic functions. These aren't UI functions that gain features and slightly change in nature every release, they're fundamental building blocks used by lock-free algorithms everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** this sounds like possible premature optimization. is this lock acquisition slowing things down?

**Edit2:** its possible compiler optimization will defeat this. be aware.

if you are concerned about the gotchas with double checked locking, perhaps `dispatch_once()` could be useful for you?

would double checked locking work in this case?

```
-(void) doSomething {
    if (!_isCanceled) { //only attempt to acquire lock if not canceled already
        @synchronized(self) {
            if (!_isCanceled) // now check again (the double check part)
                doSomethingElse();
        }
    }
}
```

read the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) on double checked locking for more info

Comment: I can't measure if it's faster if I can't do it in the first place. Double-checked locking would *almost* work here, in that you'd never see a torn result and you'd have eventual convergence… but actually the property is always checked to see if some other thing is done and without an acquire barrier you don't get the necessary synchronizes-with relation for that to work.

Comment: @Strilanc you say once it is "canceled" it can't be undone so I don't see why you cant use the check before lock acquisition (then again after if need be) to avoid locking after it has been canceled. The only thing I can think of is compiler optimization removing the check, but IIRC you can turn that off on a per-function basis now.

Comment: The problem manifests when someone conditionally uses a result that's only available after cancellation occurs. Because the happy-case doesn't have an acquire barrier, they can end up seeing the token cancelled before the result is ready.

Comment: I updated my answer to make it more clear what i mean. there is also a link for more info.

Comment: You're trying to answer my example instead of my question. I want to know how to do a read that forces an acquire barrier.

Comment: Yes, but the reason you give for wanting to know this is so that you can avoid the cost of acquiring a lock that isn't required after a certain thing happens.

Comment: double checked locking doesn't meet that criteria, for well known reasons: it creates race conditions between reading the flag and reading what the flag protects because it fails to establish synchronizes-with relations.

Comment: no reason to tell him, he is not upvoting and know better what Apple will do :))